# Disambiguating the cd tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd) serves dual use for the `cd` (change directory) command and CD as in CD-ROM/R/RW/audio. The tag isn't huge, but I'd still prefer to distinguish between them before it grows. I don't know how to name the two tags *in such a way that people who feel tempted to use `cd` and don't realize there's an ambiguity have a clear path to the right tag*. Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename \[cd\] to \[cd-command\]](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/rename-cd-to-cd-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the chat [starting here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1224200#1224200) for what we've settled on. To summarize, the plan is to leave the [cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd) for the change-directory command/bultin, but add [data-cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-cd) with an alias of [cdrom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cdrom) so that people starting to type 'cd' will see the other option and hopefully make an more informed choice. If the [cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd) tag continues to be abused, we will rename and ban it.

A [dvd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) exists for issues more specific to DVD media.

Answer (score 6):

Does [cd-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd-command) work? The suffix is kind of annoying, but the tag really needs to start with `cd` or people won't see it; we can't make it [change-directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-directory) or something. And [cd-rom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom) for the other one

Comment: After a [little chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1224200#1224200), we've gone for [tag:data-cd], with [tag:cd-rom] being a synonym. Plus an option to rename [tag:cd] to [tag:cd-command] if [tag:cd] is misused.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tag should be killed for this ambiguity thing. Someone who is asking for the `cd` command should just use the [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) tag for example. As for CDs, maybe we should just use something like [optical-disc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optical-disc), and make it a synonym to [dvd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvd) and (the not-yet-existent) [blueray](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueray). To me the important distinguishing points should be the question content.

Comment: The problem isn't so much killing the tag as deciding what to replace it with so that askers have a chance of figuring out what to use. [tag:shell] is huge, I think it's worth having additional tags for well-identified subsets such as [tag:quoting], [tag:command-history], …, including the `cd` command.

Comment: "symlink"? ----

Comment: @Hello71: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cd` is a bash builtin. There is already a `/bash` tag, but maybe consider having a `/bash-builtin` tag, if something more specific is required. I'm not completely sure of the criteria for more specialist tags, if one does exist. I think a `/cd` is a bit too specific though. It is not practical to have a tag for every command out there.

Comment: `cd` isn't specifically a bash built-in, it's a built-in in every shell, and I do think it deserves a tag (common with `pushd` and friends, probably).