# Rename [cd] to [cd-command]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Apparently [this has come](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/558/41104) to bite our behinds. [cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd) is again used for either the optical disk and the change directory command. I propose renaming [cd] to [cd-command] and re-tag whatever isn't about the command with their appropriates tags.

Recent examples of mistagging:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/180169/revisions
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/177284/revisions
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/145441/revisions

Comment: tbh is having a category for the `cd` command really a good idea anyways? Wouldn't that be basically a `bash` or `zsh` (or whatever their shell is) question? Also, it seems like `cd` is too short of a name to be unique anyways so this is kind of inevitable. Seems `cdrom` is more along the lines people are thinking of and would be hard to confuse with a shell built-in.

Comment: @Bratchley that would be another discussion.

Comment: @Bratchley `cdrom` does not work for all compact disk related cases, because some are related to CDs including audio CDs. I notice that the same applies to `data-cd`; Not sure we need a tag `compact-disk`, though...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blacklisted:

[image]

Comment: optical-disc might be a better tag, unless we want different tags for data dvds, and data blu-rays.  Or cdrom would be an ok tag, and typing cd would pop it up as an autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a handful of other mistaggings in [cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd), moved the rest to [cd-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd-command), and put in a request to blacklist [cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd)

Answer (score 1):

`/cdrom` would be a better tag than `/data-cd`, I think.  Typing `cd` would pop it up as an autocompletion, so people would discover it automatically.

Or `/optical-disc` would cover data dvds and data blu-rays, too.  We don't need or want different tags for those, do we?  Tags that are too specific mean too many tags.