# Searching for [cd] should inform the user to disambiguate the search instead of returning 0 results

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, search, cd-command

Tag in question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/cd-command

Incorrect search I performed: `[windows-subsystem-for-linux] [cd]`

Correct search: `[windows-subsystem-for-linux] [cd-command]`

---

Searching unix.meta tells me the `cd` tag has caused a lot of problems here so [it was renamed to `[cd-command]`](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/rename-cd-to-cd-command). If you try to create a question using the `cd` tag, it will give you this error:

[image]

I'd like to request analogous information when you include `[cd]` in a `https://unix.stackexchange.com/` search. Maybe the result page could provide the same information?

I'll be honest, this cost me less than a minute of time to discover I should have used `[cd-command]` instead of `[cd]`, but [it cost me 15+ minutes to learn *why* this command was renamed](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3356/101311). Maybe someday this feature will save someone else 15 minutes...

Not a huge win if implemented. As such, I won't be offended if this is downvoted to oblivion, but I do think it would provide a modicum of value.

Comment: Just a quick (side?) note: searching for non-existent tags seems to yield the same result: [foobar search](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux+foobar) gives "There are no questions tagged foobar", similar to the Q's "incorrect" search for [... cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux+cd) saying "There are no questions tagged cd", so that could be a hint that the `[cd]` portion was bogus.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, I hadn't noticed that! IMHO, it's a pretty subtle but valuable clue. Maybe if it stood out more it would solve this problem. For example, coloring the message in red or yellow, and/or coloring the text of the invalid tag in red or yellow.